# javascript - When a url is opened in one window of IE then from other window of IE on button click the already opened should come to focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, cross-browser

CASE 1: I have the above requirement in IE; that if i already open an instance of a URL from VS or a deployed URL in one window of IE (for example already opened url: www.onbuttonclick.com)
CASE 2: Now i have opened an application where i have written a button click event that on click i need to open a particular url (Working fine if www.onbuttonclick.com is opened from this button click event)

Requirement: i have to write some code in www.onbuttonclick.com that when it is getting loaded it needs to check if the url is already opened in any of the tab or other windows of IE ??????? please suggest a suitable solution....
I have tried the below approach and it is working fine if www.onbuttonclick.com is not already opened........

```
    var memberURL = document.URL;
    var newWindowCopy = document.URL;
    var winBrowser = window.clientInformation.appName;
    var stringText = window.clientInformation.userAgent.toString();
    var localVariable = "IamAliveInLocalStorage";

    if (winBrowser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" || stringText.indexOf('MSIE') >= 0) {
        if (localStorage.getItem("MyStorage") == localVariable) { 
                open(memberURL, newWindowCopy).close();
        }
        else {
            localStorage.setItem("MyStorage", localVariable);
            window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                localStorage.removeItem("MyStorage");
                localStorage.clear();
            };
        }
    }
    else { }
```

Comment: www.onbuttonClick.com url is my custom page where i can make the changes.....

Comment: can u please suggest me an alternative approach...